# Problems Installing virtualenvwrapper on mountain lion

Tags: virtualenv, pip, setuptools, osx-mountain-lion

I recently lost my HDD and am currently in the process of rebuilding my laptop (running Mountain Lion) dev system.  This afternoon I went to install virtualenvwrapper and ran into some weirdness that prevents me from installing virtualenvwrapper.

*I've done the following:*

1. Installed setup tools.
2. Used easy_install-2.7 to install pip.
3. Used pip-2.7 to install virtual env.

When I go to install virtualenvwrapper using pip-2.7, I get the following (see below).  The *-2.5,-2.6,-2.7* suffixes seem to be a new thing for mountain lion?  I've tried the same process without the suffixes, but that didn't work either.

I'm posting because I suspect something is majorly awry here, and would like to get to the bottom of it before it becomes a more insidious problem down the road.

*Is it better for me to download and install a fresh version of 2.7, and set up my paths to use it?*

---

```
Downloads  sudo pip-2.7 install virtualenvwrapper   
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Downloading/unpacking distribute (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz (627kB): 627kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

Installing collected packages: distribute
  Running setup.py install for distribute
    Before install bootstrap.
    Scanning installed packages
    Setuptools installation detected at /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
    Egg installation
    Patching...
    Renaming /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1346705360.93
    Patched done.
    Relaunching...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'install' is not defined
    Complete output from command /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RMDd1X-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    Before install bootstrap.

Scanning installed packages

Setuptools installation detected at /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg

Egg installation

Patching...

Renaming /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1346705360.93

Patched done.

Relaunching...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'install' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link:

https://gist.github.com/3179227

(using pythonbrew) seems to have sorted the issue out for me temporarily.  I'd like to not have another component in the mix (pythonbrew), so hopefully someone else will weight in with how to get virtualenv to play nicely with ML.

Answer (score 9):

What [p4tux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607964/p4tux) said

> virtualenv is now using distribute not setuptools
>
> `export VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE=true`

before you create the environment with

```
virtualenv ENV
```

or do

```
$ python virtualenv.py --distribute ENV
```

See [virtualenv documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#usage)

Answer (score 4):

virtualenv is now using distribute not setuptools

export VIRTUALENV_DISTRIBUTE=true

Comment: I'm expieriencing this, too. Could you elaborate on when this variable should be set?